# Language-ext Aggregate exceptions/failures when Try<IEnumerable<Try<...>>>

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I am fresh new with the brilliant language-ext c# library.

I have this code that returns a `Try<IEnumerable<Try<Unit>>` object:

```
            Try(DetectAlertsToNotify)
            .MapT(SendNotification)
            //treat errors happened indifferently from their source
```

Edit: DetectAlertsToNotify returns an IEnumerable of AlertDTO

What I would like to achieve is to process elegantly all exceptions or maybe the first exception whatever it happened in DetectAlertsToNotify or SendNotification.

How could I aggregate all errors or take the first error of `Try<IEnumerable<Try<Unit>>` with keeping code simple and minimum as possible?

Comment: Can you give us a little more code to work with? I'm trying to create a working version of your example, but can't find a version of `MapT` that works with `Try<Unit>`. It looks like `DetectAlertsToNotify` returns `Unit`, right? So `Try(DetectAlertsToNotify)` returns `Try<Unit>`. I don't see how to invoke `MapT` on that result, though. (I have F#/Haskell experience, but have never used LanguageExt before.)

Comment: Thanks, in fact DetectAlertsToNotify returns an IEnumerable <AlertDTO>

Comment: OK, but then where does `Try<Unit>` come from? `Try(DetectAlertsToNotify)` would return a `Try<IEnumerable<AlertDTO>>`, and I still don't see any way to apply `MapT` to that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
using LanguageExt;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;

Try<Unit> Send(string message)
{
    return Try(unit);
}

Try<Arr<string>> GetList()
{
    return Try(Array("a", "b", "c"));
}

// LINQ style (better for longer chains)
var errorOrAllResults1 =
    from inputs in GetList()
    from results in inputs.Map(Send).Sequence()
    select results;

// method style
var errorOrAllResults2 = GetList().Bind(inputs => inputs.Map(Send).Sequence());
```

Notes:

- I use `Arr<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` because this makes sure there is no enumeration outside of `Try` in case the exception might raise when enumerating. Otherwise we probably need some helper to make sure the enumeration itself is catched in some `Try`.
- `Sequence()` will change inner and outer monad (container). This turns `Arr<Try<Unit>>` into `Try<Arr<Unit>>`. We need this because we want/need to "stay" in the `Try` monad (LINQ expression).

If you look at the intermediate types you probably will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly my case and it is perfect. I was too much focused on using MapT to keep all expressions on the same level. Now I see the point of staying in the same monad with Bind.